# Inequality of the dimension of the formal power series ring when the ring is non-noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

We generally know that if $R$ is Noetherian then we have that $\dim (R[[X]])=\dim(R)+1$.

> If we drop the assumption that $R$ is Noetherian does the inequality $\dim (R[[x]]) \geq \dim(R)+1 $ hold true?

I know that the inverse inequality does not hold when we drop the Noetherian assumption as in the paper *Krull Dimension in Power Series Rings* by Jimmy T. Arnold we can find non-noetherian rings whose power series have infinite dimension but the dimension of the ring is finite.

Comment: The title is inappropriate. You don't want any counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proof is the same as for polynomial rings. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $\mathfrak{p}[[X]]$ is a prime ideal in $R[[X]]$ since the quotient is $(R/\mathfrak{p})[[X]]$, which is an integral domain. But also $\mathfrak{p} + \langle X \rangle$ is a prime ideal in $R[[X]]$, since the quotient is $R/\mathfrak{p}$.

Thus, if $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subset \dotsc \subset \mathfrak{p}_n$ is a chain of prime ideals in $R$, then $\mathfrak{p}_0[[X]] \subset \dotsc \subset \mathfrak{p}_n[[X]] \subset \mathfrak{p}_n + \langle X \rangle$ is a chain of prime ideals in $R[[X]]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!